# SSH to virtual machine works only in one specific way

Tags: networking, ssh

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on VMware Workstation 16 Player. I installed SSH server. To test it I did not use any key-pair, but only password.
From the Windows host the only way I can SSH into the machine is by using the command `ssh username@<LAN IP address*>`. *address as seen in `ip a` command on Ubuntu near `inet`

If I try to use the same command from another PC I will get `ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection timed out`. (But that's obvious, because the IP is internal for the same network of the virtual machine and the Windows host)

But, If I try to use `ssh username@localhost` (from the Windows host)I get "ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused"

Also, If I try to use `ssh username@<public IP address>` I get `ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused`

To sum it up, the only way I can SSH to this virtual machine is from the host it runs from, and only using `ssh username@<LAN IP address*>`
*address as seen in `ip a` near `inet`

How to fix it? how to be able to SSH to it from other PCs on the internet as well?

Thanks

Comment: This really sounds more like an issue with the VMWARE networking configuration than with the Ubuntu guest - in particular, it sounds like the network is configured using NAT and you need to forward traffic from an available host port to your Ubuntu guest's SSH port.

Comment: It was indeed NAT, I changed to bridged but it's still timed out. Should i change back to NAT?

Comment: If you change to bridged mode, you will need to use the IP address shown beside the `inet` keyword to connect from both the VmWare host and other LAN hosts. You would still need to port forward across your "real" NAT (i.e. router) to connect using your public IP from outside the LAN.